# Difference between mailComposeDelegate and simple Delegate property

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Hi i am getting confuse on `MFMailComposeViewController` delegate property, when i set `mailer.mailComposeDelegate` app crash just after call `[self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];` and when i do `mailer.delegate` then app don't crash but its view can't hide after sending mail or just cancel it from its navigation bat button "Cancel". I am getting stuck why this happen. 
Let me share code, you get hint where i am doing mistake.

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if(mailer)
    {
        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        //mailer.delegate=self;
        [mailer setSubject:@"What the Buck?"];
        imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenImgSubCat);        

        [mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"testapp"];        
        NSString *emailBody = @"What the Buck?! – www.testapp.com";
        [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
        [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
        //[mailer release];

    }
}
}
```

**Updated**

I change code and use `mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;` and also comment this line  `[mailer release];` still giving me crash on when image is being loading.
Here is the Image what i am getting after crash.
[image]

Comment: your message body is not actually a valid HTML - pass NO to isHTML parameter, may be this might help

Comment: I changed this but still getting crash :(.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .h file are you adding  `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`

```
@interface VideoPlayAndSharing : UIViewController
<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

Display ComposerSheet

```
-(void)displayComposerSheet
{
    if ((videodta.length/1024)/1024 < 25)
    {
        NSLog(@"Video size >> %d",videodta.length/1024);
        MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [picker setSubject:@"Your subject"];


        // Set up recipients
        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"rajneesh071@gmail.com"];
        NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com", @"third@example.com", nil];
        NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"fourth@example.com"];

        [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
        [picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];
        [picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

        [picker addAttachmentData:videodta mimeType:@"video/mp4" fileName:@"MyPersonalMessage"];

        // Fill out the email body text
        NSString *emailBody = @"Type your message here";
        [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Personal Message"
                                                        message:@"Video exceed the limit of 25 MB"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

and delegate method

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{   
    // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            message.text = @"Result: canceled";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            message.text = @"Result: saved";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            message.text = @"Result: sent";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            message.text = @"Result: failed";
            break;
        default:
            message.text = @"Result: not sent";
            break;
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**EDIT**

`picker.mailComposeDelegate` its delegate of `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`

Its respond to `- (void)mailComposeController`

`picker.delegate` its delegate of `UINavigationControllerDelegate`

Its respond to navigation controller not `- (void)mailComposeController` , so on cancel click it will not call, thats why your `MFMailComposeViewController` view is not hiding.

Comment: Yes Exactly, as i told i am getting crash while loading image data as attachment.

Comment: hey problem is with your image data

Comment: check your image data... or try to check using                  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"raj_iAmTheDeveloper.jpg"];
        NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [mailer addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"MyPersonalImage"];

Comment: Image is fine, because i am sharing same image on Facebook and when i do mailer.delegate=self; instead of mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;, it load image perfectly fine.

Comment: Right, what was the problem? because i have the same issue and nothing here is helping..

Comment: @Rajneesh071 , I had understood that, but still didn't change anything. Anyway I found out what my problem was and it might help anyone else: All the sending and MFMailComposeViewController object was created inside another object which was nilled right after sending the mail. Therefore MFMailComposeViewController's didFinishWithResult callback would call a place in memory which was not the delegate's didFinishWithResult anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Add MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate delegate in your .h file first & then check again.and also mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self; is right way not mailer.delegate=self also change it in your code and then check.

## import MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h this in .m with less than and greater than sign and also add MessageUI.framework.

```
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"vishal@ldh.01s.in"]; 
[mail setToRecipients:toRecipients];
```

add these two lines before set message body and then check.

Comment: I changed to mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self; and remove [mailer release]; but it still giving me crash on loading. let me share with you image, check my question under updated.

Comment: Nope. This is just a delegate declaration, it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Comment following line
[mailer release];

I think it causing the problem

Comment: commented but still giving me error when i am loading image as attachment into mail.

Comment: Do one thing.NSLog the imagedata.What it come? Also try any sample image instead of screenImgSubCat which present in your application bundle NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"SampleImage.png"]);

Comment: Image is fine, because i am sharing same image on Facebook and when i do  mailer.delegate=self; instead of mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;, it load image perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

check the headers - delegate property is of type `id <UINavigationControllerDelegate>` - because mail composer inherits from it, so, setting this to something might be a bad idea due to internal shenanigans of composer, to get notifications of mail composer state set self as composer's mailComposeDelegate.

Comment: Now i set this but as i told you it still giving me crash. check my updated question.