# Iphone app getting crashing when i enter the iphone mail sheet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, mfmailcomposer

In my iphone app. I'm Creating Iphone Mail Chat Sheet using `MFMailComposeViewController`. Now when I enter the second time,the mail sheet, my app is getting crashed. I searched in Google. But I couldn't find the solution. Anybody help me to solve my issue. PLease see this below code and help me where am I doing wrong.

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
        {
            controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [controller setSubject:@""];
            [controller setToRecipients:array1];
            [controller setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
            [controller setMailComposeDelegate: self];
            [controller setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
            [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];
            [controller release];
        }

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{
    if(result == MFMailComposeResultSent)
    {
        [[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else if (result == MFMailComposeResultCancelled)
    {
        [[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
 }
```

Comment: which version of the xcode you are using?

Comment: What error is your NSLog showing?

Comment: @PratyushaTerli thanks for you reply. NSlog Shows Null Value.

Comment: Can you please check your console and see if any crash message is there? Copy paste the console log statements and paste in your question. If there are no crash message type bt and press enter in console.

Comment: @Gopinath, Your crash log says that you are trying to call `showErrorMessage` which is not there in myViewContrl object. That is the reason for crash. Remove `[self showErrorMessage:` and check. It will work.

Comment: check my answer... for better help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491345/difference-between-mailcomposedelegate-and-simple-delegate-property/13491442#13491442

Comment: check that you are login with mail account or not....

Comment: @Rajneesh071 ya. it is in login.

Comment: check my updated answer there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491345/difference-between-mailcomposedelegate-and-simple-delegate-property/13491442#13491442

Comment: change your line [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];

Answer (score 0):

I think this code makes the issue:

```
[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Instead of the above use:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. sorry. I got the issue. Now when i enter the second time to the mail sheet i click the send button. my app getting crashing. What can i do. What is the Problem of this issue?

Comment: @Gopinath, can you give us the crash log?

Comment: @Gopinath: please check the viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear methods of your navigation controller view class

Comment: @Aadhira Thanks for reply. -[myViewContrl showErrorMessage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x883a400

Comment: @Gopinath: then issue is with the showErrorMessage method call. Where are  you calling that method ? Also check my previous comment

Comment: @MidhunMP Ya. thanks for you reply. Ya. I have checked showErrorMessage this method am calling in the same class. And also i have  viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear method. I want to add anything in inside of these methods.

Comment: @Gopinath: where are you calling that method ? I think that method is being called after dismissing the view.

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491345/difference-between-mailcomposedelegate-and-simple-delegate-property/13491442#13491442

Answer (score 0):

try to write this delegate method instead of you have writen the same method

and let me know whether it is working or not!!!!

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        NSLog(@"canceled");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        NSLog(@"saved");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        NSLog(@"sent");
        [self showErrorMessage: @"Email sent successfully"];
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        NSLog(@"failed");
        [self showErrorMessage: @"Failed to send email"];
        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"not sent");
        break;
}
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

happy coding!!!!!!!

Comment: thanks for your help. But when i enter secound time in mail sheet i clicked sent button. then my app getting crashing. But in my console i got this error. -[myviewcontroler showErrorMessage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x883a400

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];
```

with:

```
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.Sorry. i got this error in console. -[myViewCotroler showErrorMessage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9839a00

Comment: @Gopinath, remove that line which `[self showErrorMessage:` and check.

Comment: @ACB May i know the problem of this issue?

Comment: @Gopinath, You need to post your `showErrorMessage` and the line where you are calling this method. There is a serious mismatch between these two. That is the reason for crashing.

Comment: @ACB sorry for the delay. please wait.

Comment: @Gopinath, Check my answer and let me know. That should fix it.

Comment: @ACB sorry. i deleted that showErrorMessage line. And also i got crashing. what can i do?.

Comment: Can you post the crash message which is there now after removing that? What is the new crash?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20917/discussion-between-gopinath-and-acb)

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491345/difference-between-mailcomposedelegate-and-simple-delegate-property/13491442#13491442

Answer (score 0):

in method which you are opening the mail view ,replace your code with the below code.and tell me whether it is working or not!!!!!! happy coding!!!!

```
 MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] == NO) {
        return;
}
else
{
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    NSString *stringtitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Apple"];
    [picker setSubject:stringtitle];

    NSData *imgDataLoop = UIImagePNGRepresentation(shaereImage.image);

    [picker addAttachmentData:imgDataLoop mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"rainy"];

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    [picker release];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your methods to,

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"canceled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"sent");
            [self showErrorMessage: @"Email sent successfully"];
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"failed");
            [self showErrorMessage: @"Failed to send email"];
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"not sent");
            break;
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}

-(void)showErrorMessage:(NSString *)iMessage
{
        NSLog(@"%@", iMessage);
}
```

As I mentioned earlier, your method signature was different while calling and in the definition part. It should be the same at both places as shown above.

While calling the method was `[self showErrorMessage: @"Failed to send email"];` but in definition you were not accepting the string part. You need to have an input param for the same. You can also do the same by calling it as `[self showErrorMessage];` and then keep the `showErrorMessage` method as it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)mail
{ 
  if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailController setSubject:@"your Subject"];
    [mailController setMessageBody:@"your message" isHTML:NO];

    UIImage *tmp = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"];
    NSData *myData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tmp, 1.0);

    [mailController addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"MyPhoto.png"];
    if (arrTo)
        [mailController setToRecipients:arrTo];

    [self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
    return YES;
}
else {
    return NO;
}
}
}
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{   

    [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```